# Getting Response from created library

Tags: android, android-library

My objective is to create a reusable libraries that I could just include if i will to make new project. Example for this is **login**.

I will create the **login** project separately, do the design and coding. Now, if I will going to use it in one of my projects, I will just have to include it as a **dependency**. So far, this is working, the login displayed in my new project.

**The challenge** that I encounter is how to treat or get the response of the results of the login to my application. Since they are separate projects,

What would be the best strategy for this. Or are there any better ways to create a reusable libraries.

Thanks

Comment: Is your 'login component' an `Activity` or it's a `Fragment` ?

Comment: I used fragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment).

Comment: im trying to use singleton but i can't still figure out the logic. hope you could give some logic for this.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interactivity between an `Activity` and a `Fragment` (which has been loaded on that `Activity`) is quite easy. You can add a public method to that `Fragment` and then call it in your `Activity` methods. Otherwise if your login process is a asynchronous task (i.e is going to be done in background thread), you probably need an interface to inform parent `Activity` that login process has been done.

Here's some code snippets for getting started.

```
public LoginFrag extends Fragment {
    // Other stuff        

    /* This is your own method which checks user credentials */
    public void check() {
        boolean success = false;

        // codes for checking username and password
        // and then update 'success' variable

        // with this code you'll inform the parent activity
        if(mListener != null) {
            mListener.onResult(success);
        }
    }

    OnLoginResultListener mListener;        

    public void setOnLoginResultListener(OnLoginResultListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }        

    public interface OnLoginResultListener {
        public void onResult(boolean success);
    }
}
```

This is the parent Activity codes:

```
public MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        //Other stuff
        LoginFrag login = new LoginFrag(); // from the library
        login.setOnLoginResultListener(new OnLoginResultListener(){

            @Override
            public void onResult(boolean success) {
                // do stuff here with 'success' for example:
                String message;
                if(success) {
                    message = "Congratulation! you've logged in";
                } else {
                    message = "Ooops! login failed!";
                }
                console.log(message);
            }
        });

        // Now load this fragment by 'FragmentManager'
        // via 'getSupportFragmentManager()'
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for sharing your snippets. I'll check this out. by the way, can u also post the snippet used in creating the OnLoginResultListener. This is my first time to create classes like this. I think i need a guide to not messed up anything.

Comment: @chulolots Java interfaces can't be implemented! all of their method is public abstract, so you can't implement them, google java interface for more info